# Is it possible to get "autorisation provisoire de séjour" (APS) after leaving France?

Tags: france, indian-citizens, erasmus

I am an Indian citizen currently enrolled in an Erasmus Mundus MSc 2 year program. Under this program I have to study in 2 different European countries for 1 year each. The MSc program consists of getting two Master degrees from each of the two countries which collectively form the MSc (*I don't get the any final degree until I finish my second year*).

For my first year, I did Master-2 in France and then moved to UK to do the 2nd year of the program. I could not apply for APS (*"autorisation provisoire de séjour"*) while I was in France because *technically* my course wasn't finished (*and I didn't get the degree from France as it's only awarded after completing two years program*). This year my course will get over and I will get the Master-2 from France as well as a Master's degree from UK.

My French Visa has already expired so I don't have carte de sejour however, I can get an attestation from the University in France stating that I had to leave France for 2nd year of the program.

Will it be possible for me to apply for and APS now, after I get my Master-2 degree from France?

Comment: https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F17319 mentions that you must hold a valid 'carte de séjour étudiant' to request an APS. But your case is on the edge.

Comment: Indeed, when I had 'carte de sejour' my course was not finished, so I could not apply for APS then as one of the condition for APS is that your studies should have finished.

Comment: Someone in a similar situation to yours came back to France on a visitors visa in the weeks before the end of the University year, applied at the prefecture for a student visa based on the fact that he was technically still enrolled at the university and then applied for an APS. It was complicated and expensive but it worked.

Comment: @Galaxy glad it worked. Could you also provide information about how they handled the missing Carte de Sejour? 
Did they apply for a student visa and then 'carte de sejour' and then APS or were they exempt from getting a 'Carte de Sejour'?